# Growing celosia outside in the UK

Tags: plant-care, flowers, planting, greenhouse

Can celosia plants be planted outside in the soil in UK climate?

I have a small spiky celosia that I purchased from a gardening centre, where it was stored in a polytunnel. I understand that these plants prefer warm, humid temperatures. Is it impossible for them to grow in garden soil in the UK, or is there a way for this to be achieved?

I do have a plastic PVC greenhouse. Would this be more suitable?

Comment: Great question fortunia88! mmmmmm

Answer (score 3):

*Celosia* are half hardy annuals in the UK; they can be planted outdoors as part of a summer bedding scheme, but they are frost sensitive and need hardening off prior to planting out; they need a warm and sheltered spot.

They can also be kept as temporary, short lived houseplants; indoors in coolish temperatures (around 15-20 degC) they will flower for a longer period than they will outdoors in summer heat. Indoors or  out, they are discarded once flowering is finished.

Comment: What does hardening off mean please? I'm a newbie...

Comment: This has been explained somewhere, but I can't find it... It means  to place the plant outdoors between 11-3 (not in full sun), bring it back in, then extend the time period its outdoors over about a week or so until finally, its outside all night (preferably a milder night). Then you can plant outdoors...It just means a gradual accllimiatization to new conditiions outdoors...this time of year in the UK you can do it over 3 or 4 days if we're having a warm spell without cold nights.